# how to acurately measure the bitrate flowing through a named pipe?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

if i have `proc1 | proc2` is there a way to accurately measure the bitrate flowing through the pipe , without altering the behaviour as if the measuring device were not there?  would something like tee work ok? would i want `proc1 | tee proc2 > flow_measurement_thing` or `proc1 | tee flow_measurement_thing > proc2`?   if i understand pipes correctly , unix pipes by default can chew on 4096 bytes and they can block if the receiver is not reading data out as fast as it's coming in, so i'm concerned the measurement device itself might cause 'laminar' flow through the pipe to become 'turbulent' if i don't implement it correctly.

the actual use case is glued up in python , with named pipes from os.. here's a greatly simplified example

```
import os, subprocess
os.mkfifo('pipe')
subprocess.Popen(['convert', '-i', 'pipe', '-o', 'somewhere_else'])
subprocess.Popen(['capture', '-o', 'pipe'])
```

for simplicity's sake let's assume that converter does not modify the bitrate, then i want to be able to verify that `capture | convert | /dev/null` is pumping bits at the same rate as `capture | /dev/null`

Comment: does pv (pipe-viewer) help?  http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

Comment: yes, that does just the trick.  thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Corey Goldberg said, you should use `pv`.  It's a very nice tool and available on most *nix systems.  You could do these things:

```
capture | pv > /dev/null
capture | convert | pv > /dev/null
```

`pv` will tell you the throughput for each case.

Or, if the output of `capture` is deterministic, just use a timer.

Comment: How do I force `pv` to express the throughput in b/s? I'm trying to measure WLAN throughput at various positions using `netcat`. Currently I'm just using Gnome System Monitor to measure the throughput of the WiFi interface, but in the future I'd like to use a command line tool like `pv`.

Comment: @JamesHaigh: on my system (Mac OS with MacPorts, using `port install pv`), pv prints B/s (bytes per second).  If you're saying you need bits instead of bytes, well, just multiply by 8.  ;)

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I want it in b/s in _realtime_. Is there some command line magic to chop up the stderr, multiply the value by 8, and reconstruct the output to work in the same manner as `pv`'s normal output? I like the way that `pv` refreshes in place, but for now I'll just monitor the network interface using tools that I know how to express the values in b/s.

Comment: @JamesHaigh: I don't know, I think you're better off doing what you say using network monitoring tools for monitoring the network.  `pv` to me is more of a quick and dirty tool to augment my interactive CLI work.